# Willkommen + Präposition (bei / zu / in)?

Tags: word-usage, preposition

Wenn man jemanden willkommen heißt, folgt auf das *Willkommen* – sofern der Satz noch weiter geht – oft eine Präposition: *bei*, *zu*, oder *in*.

Mir scheint, die verwendete Präposition hängt dabei von der Art des Willkommens ab:
zum Beispiel eine Präposition für unbestimmte Orte wie Länder, eine andere für Ereignisse wie Talkshows und eine dritte für bestimmte Orte wie das Zuhause.

> Willkommen in Deutschland.
>   Willkommen bei Hart aber Fair!
>   Willkommen zu Hause.

Wann wird welche Präposition mit Willkommen verwendet?
Gibt es dafür eine Regel und wie lautet sie?

Comment: ich moechte nur wissen, wenn ich zu, in oder bei nutzen und  in welcher Situation kann ich jener davon nutzen

Comment: Vollständige Beispielsätze wären trotzdem hilfreich, da der Gebrauch dieser Präpositionen im konkreten Fall weitgehend austauschbar sein kann.

Comment: verstanden, gibt es keine feste Regelung.  Danke schoen

Comment: Was spricht dagegen, dass Sie einfach Ihre Frage [edit]ieren, wie vorgeschlagen. Für manche Fälle sind die Präpositionen austaschbar, für Andere nicht.

Comment: `einen ungewählten Ort spricht` Wie kommt da denn auf einmal ein *ä* hin? Wenn du die Umlaute mit deiner Tastatur schreiben kannst, wäre es vorteilhaft diese auch zu nutzen.

Comment: Die Wahl der richtigen Präposition hat nichts mit dem Willkommensein an sich zu tun, sondern mit dem Ort der Handlung (hier eben zufällig das Willkommensein). Die Frage sollte also eher lauten: _Wovon hängt die Wahl der richtigen Präposition im Dativ ab?_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt leider keine gute Antwort auf diese Frage. Die Phrase

> Willkommen …

ist eine Abkürzung von

> Ich *heiße* dich/euch/Sie … willkommen.

Das Verb *heißen* in der Bedeutung *nennen*, *auffordern* hat aber keine bevorzugte Präposition, neben *willkommen* steht eine freie adverbiale Bestimmung.

Man kann da praktisch alles außer einer Richtung verwenden.

> Willkommen im 21. Jahrhundert.
>
> Willkommen zwischen Tür und Angel.
>
> Willkommen beim Kartoffelschälen.
>
> Willkommen zum Zweck des Kennenlernens.
>
> Willkommen für ein Wiedersehen.
>
> Willkommen zuhause.

Comment: Dazu könnte [dieser Artikel](https://www.welt.de/kultur/history/article13820925/Willkommen-zu-bei-an-Was-stimmt-denn-nun.html) der Zeitung Die Welt interessant sein. Hier wird behauptet, dass „bei” oder „in“ die linguistisch korrekten Präpositionen wären, wohingegen „zu“ nur zum Angeben eines Zweckes oder Ziels benutzt werden sollte.

Answer (score 0):

**Willkommen + in + Ort** ist richtig.

**Willkommen + zu + etwas** ist eher für Anlässe und Gemeinschaften wie Geburtstagsfeier.

**Willkommen + bei**  wird selten verwendet. Im Beispiel Sendung xy hilft es, sich zu merken, dass es darum geht, da**bei** zu sein.